# How to include the client from openapi-generator in a gradle java application?

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to create a gradle java application that generates a client from an openAPI specification file and uses that client.
So I created a java application with `gradle init` (type:application, language:Java, DSL:groovy, test-framework:Junit Jupiter, project-name:simple-java-app, package-structure:`a.aa`).

### Small example of what works:

I can create a new source folder `second/loc/src/main/java` with a package `b.bb` and a class `Foo`.
And with the following `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    second {
        java {
            srcDir 'second/loc/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    source += sourceSets.second.java
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'a.aa.App'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The main class can access `Foo`:

```
package a.aa;

import b.bb.Foo;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Foo().sayFoo());
    }
}
```

### What doesn't work

Now I try the same for generated code by `openapi-generator`:

Under `plugins` I add `id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"`

And I add a new task:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/specs/petstore.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"
     configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
}
```

Then I execute the task `openApiGenerate` and confirm in the file system that the sources have been generated(eclipse won't show the build folder).
Now I use the same method as above resulting in below `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/specs/petstore.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
}

sourceSets {
    client {
        java {
            srcDir '$buildDir/generated/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    source += sourceSets.client.java
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'a.aa.App'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But when I try to use the classes now:

```
package a.aa;

import org.openapi.example.model.Pet;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pet p = new Pet(0L);
        System.out.println(p.getId());
    }
}
```

neither import nor `Pet` can be resolved.

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\...\simple-java-app\src\main\java\a\aa\App.java:6: error: package org.openapi.example.model does not exist
import org.openapi.example.model.Pet;
                                ^
C:\...\simple-java-app\src\main\java\a\aa\App.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        Pet p = new Pet(0);
        ^
  symbol:   class Pet
  location: class App
C:\...\simple-java-app\src\main\java\a\aa\App.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        Pet p = new Pet(0);
                    ^
  symbol:   class Pet
  location: class App
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I don't know how to debug this, frankly I'm unsure if source sets are even  the right way. All openapi-generator tutorials seem to use them, I haven't tried subprojects yet, the openApiGenerate task seems to create a complete project with `build.gradle` and everything.

Comment: the generated classes, are inside the classpath ? or inside '$buildDir/generated' ? ? if they are not in the classpath, then the builder correctly throws the `cannot find symbol`. You will either make an external-reference/dependency or directly export them in a client package inside your project

Comment: The generated sources are in  `'$buildDir/generated'`. I thought adding to `source` was enough. Can you tell me how to add them to the classpath? I've tried `sourceSets.main { compileClasspath += x  }` with x = `sourceSets.client.java` (same error) | `srcDir '$buildDir/generated'` (`Could not find method srcDir() for arguments`) | `'$buildDir/generated'` (`Cannot cast [...] ArrayList to [...] FileCollection `)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the sources from the generated code to your project. One example from one of my projects:

`sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "${buildDir}/generated/src/main/java"`

After generation make sure you refresh gradle and project.

Comment: That works! (For future visitors: I still had to copy the dependencies from the generated `build.gradle` to the main `build.gradle`.)

Comment: I'm coming from Maven and was wondering if gradle plugins are able to add folders to to source theirself? Good Maven plugins did that on their own.

Comment: I feel this approach is flawed, doesn't it ignore the dependencies listed in the generated projects build.gradle files? If it works its because you have those same dependencies in your project already (potentially at different versions to those of the client).

Comment: My code generates correctly the java classes but I can't import the generated classes. I added sourceSets directory to my app/build.gradle but still not working. ¿Any help pls?

Comment: Additionally to this, you may need to make the compilation depend on source-generation: `tasks.compileJava.dependsOn('openApiGenerate')`

Answer (score 3):

With `build.gradle.kts` and gradle 7+ I used in Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
configure<SourceSetContainer> {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/src/main/java")
    }
}
```

To add the java generated sources to the project's source.