# How to add OpenAPI client as a subproject?

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I can successfully [add a generated openapi client to my project via source sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63054564/3014199). But then I have to copy dependencies into the main `build-gradle`, resolve conflicts -> I think it would be a better design to have the client as a subproject with its own `build.gradle`.

So I add `include = 'build:openapi-java-client'` to my `settings.gradle` and `compile project(':build:openapi-java-client')` to my dependencies. So that I have the following files:
`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/specs/petstore.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/openapi-java-client".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    
    compile project(':build:openapi-java-client')
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'a.aa.App'
}
```

and `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'simple-java-app'
include = 'build:openapi-java-client'
```

I execute `openApiGenerate` in advance, after adding it as a subproject, I do Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project and Refresh.

Eclipse then shows me a problem:

```
Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip'.
Settings file 'C:\...\simple-java-app\settings.gradle' line: 11
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'simple-java-app'.
Could not set unknown property 'include' for settings 'simple-java-app' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
```

I don't know where to go from here, addressing subprojects in subfolders worked just fine when I worked through https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/ and put `greeting-library` in a subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make `build/` a project when that directory specifically is not meant to be a project directory. It's Gradle default *build* directory and likely 99% of other plugins and other Gradle plugins.

Simply change `output` directory to something else other than `build/`:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("java")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/specs/petstore.json")
    outputDir.set("$rootDir/openapi-java-client")
    apiPackage.set("org.openapi.example.api")
    invokerPackage.set("org.openapi.example.invoker")
    modelPackage.set("org.openapi.example.model")
}
```

Then include the project in your build with the correct syntax:

```
// settings.gradle
include("openapi-java-client")
```

However, using the `org.openapi.generator` seems to generate an invalid `build.gradle` since I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\fmate\code\example\openapi-java-client\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\fmate\code\example\openapi-java-client\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\fmate\code\example\openapi-java-client\build.gradle': 23: unexpected char: '\' @ line 23, column 35.
         main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main\java']
```

This obviously won't work how you wanted it to since it appears to be an issue with the Gradle plugin itself. If you just need to include the generate code in your project, then just include the generated Java code as part of your main Java source:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("java")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/specs/petstore.json")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/openapi-java-client")
    apiPackage.set("org.openapi.example.api")
    invokerPackage.set("org.openapi.example.invoker")
    modelPackage.set("org.openapi.example.model")
}

tasks {
    compileJava {
        dependsOn(openApiGenerate)
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir(files("${openApiGenerate.outputDir.get()}/src/main"))
        }
    }
}
```

But with this approach, you'll run into missing imports/dependencies. It doesn't appear this plugin offers the ability to just generate the models/POJOs only, so [updating the `library` property to `native`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md) and including some missing dependencies manually, it all works:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "5.0.0-beta"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = "io.mateo.test"

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.11.1"))
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    implementation("org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.1")
    implementation("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2")
    implementation("io.swagger:swagger-core:1.6.2")
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("java")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/specs/petstore.json")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/openapi-java-client")
    apiPackage.set("org.openapi.example.api")
    invokerPackage.set("org.openapi.example.invoker")
    modelPackage.set("org.openapi.example.model")
    library.set("native")
    configOptions.put("dateLibrary", "java8")
}

tasks {
    compileJava {
        dependsOn(openApiGenerate)
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir(files("${openApiGenerate.outputDir.get()}/src/main"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot configure it alike this, because `build` most certainly is an output directory, which would create a circular reference. Better try to add a new module and add that generator plugin into that module. If you can configure another module as `outputDir`, this could be referenced.

Even if the plugin resides in the root project, the destination needs to be a module.

The point is, that the root project always executes, opposite to module configutions.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65506449/1797912) a very similar question. While my answer there is not perfect, I would personally still prefer the approach suggested there – and kind of repeated here:

### Suggested Approach

I would keep the *builds* of the modules that depend on the generated API completely separate from the *build* that generates the API. The only connection between such builds should be a dependency declaration. That means, you’ll have to manually make sure to build the API generating project first and only build the dependent projects afterwards.

By default, this would mean to also publish the API module before the dependent projects can be built. An alternative to this default would be [Gradle composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) – for example, to allow you to test a newly generated API locally first before publishing it. However, before creating/running the composite build, you would have to manually run the API generating build each time that the OpenAPI document changes.

#### Example

Let’s say you have project A depending on the generated API. Its Gradle build would contain something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:api:1.0'
}
```

Of course, the `simple-java-app` build described in the question would have to be adapted to produce a module with these coordinates:

```
openApiGenerate {
    // …
    groupId = "com.example"
    id = "api"
    version = "1.0"
}
```

Before running A’s build, you’d first have to run

1. `./gradlew openApiGenerate` from your `simple-java-app` project.
2. `./gradlew publish` from the `simple-java-app/build/openapi-java-client/` directory.

Then A’s build could fetch the published dependency from the publishing repository.

Alternatively, you could drop step 2 locally and run A’s build with an additional Gradle CLI option:

```sh
./gradlew --include-build $path_to/simple-java-app/build/openapi-java-client/ …
```