# How to generate, compile, jar, and depend on a gradle module

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a Java Gradle project that uses an OpenAPI specified API. I've used the `org.openapi.generator` plugin which generates sources as well as a complete Gradle module.

I expect that there's a way to define the generate, compile, jar steps such that I can have other modules depend on the generated module.

I.e.

```
# api/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.0.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileJava.dependsOn "openApiGenerate"

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "java"
    inputSpec = "$projectDir/src/main/openapi/spec.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated"
    apiPackage = "com.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "com.example.api.invoker"
    modelPackage = "com.example.api.model"
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            library    : "native"
    ]
    groupId = "com.example"
    id = "api"
}
```

`gradlew api:openApiGenerate` generates (extraneous files elided):

```
api/build/generated/
├── build.gradle
├── pom.xml
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main/java/...
    └── test/java/...
```

Is there some way I can delegate-to, include, or depend on this generated module from other modules in the project? The generated module has a reliable `group:artifact:version` coordinate.

I.e. I'd like to be able to specify `com.example:api:1.0` elsewhere in the project.

---

I've had a read through of https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html as that seemed to be close to what I expect, but I am new to Gradle and it was a little to deep.

I've tried overriding the main and test source sets in `api/build.gradle` but I dislike having to copy and paste the dependencies from the `api/build/generated/build.gradle`.

I found https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:dependency-types which includes a tantalizing example but falls down as it is a source-only dependency.

```
dependencies {
    implementation files("$buildDir/classes") {
        builtBy 'compile'
    }
}
```

I looked at this example but how do I depend on a project (`api/build/generated/`) that does not exist yet?

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! I don’t have a perfect answer but hopefully the following will still help.

### Suggested Approach

I would keep the *builds* of the modules that depend on the generated API completely separate from the *build* that generates the API. The only connection between such builds should be a dependency declaration. That means, you’ll have to manually make sure to build the API generating project first and only build the dependent projects afterwards.

By default, this would mean to also publish the API module before the dependent projects can be built. An alternative to this default would indeed be composite builds – for example, to allow you to test a newly generated API locally first before publishing it. However, before creating/running the composite build, you would have to manually run the API generating build each time that the OpenAPI document changes.

#### Example

Let’s say you have project A depending on the generated API. Its Gradle build would contain something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:api:1.0'
}
```

Before running A’s build, you’d first have to run

1. `./gradlew openApiGenerate` from your `api` project.
2. `./gradlew publish` from the `api/build/generated/` directory.

Then A’s build could fetch the published dependency from the publishing repository.

Alternatively, you could drop step 2 locally and run A’s build with an additional Gradle CLI option:

```sh
./gradlew --include-build $path_to/api/build/generated/ …
```

### Idea for Less Manual Work

I have thought quite a bit about this but didn’t come up with any complete solution – hence my imperfect suggestion above. Let me still summarize my idea for how this *could* work.

- You would have a Gradle build which generates the API – similar to your `api` project. That build would also be committed to your VCS.
- That build would publish the generated API, even if it wouldn’t produce it itself. Instead, it would somehow delegate to the Gradle build generated by the `openApiGenerate` task. The delegation would have to happen via a [`GradleBuild` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/GradleBuild.html).
  Here lies the crux: all information on dependencies and published artifacts would effectively have to be retrieved via the Gradle CLI. I doubt that that’s currently possible.
- Projects that dependend on the API could then include the `api`-like Gradle project in a composite build without requiring the manual hassle from the approach above.

Comment: adding to your answer,  below code in gradle build file can be handy:
`sourceSets{ 
main{
java.srcDirs+=path_to/api/build/generated/ 
}
}`

Comment: Thanks, Sunil, I believe the OP has already tried that approach but ruled it out – quoting from the question: “I've tried overriding the main and test source sets in `api/build.gradle` but I dislike having to copy and paste the dependencies from the `api/build/generated/build.gradle`.”

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Chriki's answer with what I've actually used:

1. Define `api/` as it's own project with an empty `api/settings.gradle` file.

   This tells gradle that it is a self-contained project.
2. Define the api module with:

   ```
   # api/build.gradle
   plugins {
      id 'java'
      id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.0.0"
   }

   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }

   openApiGenerate {
      generatorName = "java"
      inputSpec = "$projectDir/src/main/openapi/specification.yaml"
      outputDir = "$buildDir/generated"
      apiPackage = "com.example.api"
      invokerPackage = "com.example.api.invoker"
      modelPackage = "com.example.api.model"
      configOptions = [
         dateLibrary: "java8",
         library    : "native"
      ]
      groupId = "com.example"
      id = "api"
      version = "1.0.0"
   }
   ```

   Note the `group` and `id` (and `version`) explicitly define its maven coordinate.
3. Include the build with a substitution so that the dependents can just use its maven coordinate:

   ```
   # settings.gradle

   includeBuild('api/build/generated') {
       dependencySubstitution {
           substitute module('com.example:api') with project(':')
       }
   }
   ```

   ... and in some other module:

   ```
   # app/build.gradle

   dependencies {
      implementation group: 'com.example', name: 'api'
   }
   ```

   The main advantage of this over `./gradlew --include-build api/build/generated` is that [my] IDE will 'link' it all up too.
4. Generate the API library:

   ```
    ./gradlew --project-dir api/ openApiGenerate
   ```
5. Build/run the main project:

   ```
    ./gradlew build
    ./gradlew run
   ```